Why is coin different from poin in WinBUGS
I have the following WinBUGS model and the output densities of interest. I want to understand why the density of coin is different from that of poin. Understanding this will help me to understand other things in BUGS.
model{
    y<-1
    ###########################
    y ~ dbern(theta.true)
    theta.true <- theta[coin]
    coin ~ dcat(p[])
    poin ~ dcat(p[])
    for (i in 1:3){
        p[i] <- 1/3;
        theta[i] <- 0.25*i;
        coin.prob[i] <- equals(coin,i);
    }


